# Show Modern/Metro UI permanently on one of two monitors

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, extended-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get Windows 8 to run 2 Metro apps on each display of an extended display?](https://superuser.com/questions/458662/how-do-i-get-windows-8-to-run-2-metro-apps-on-each-display-of-an-extended-displa)

I have two monitors and I'd like have Moderm/Metro UI opened in Monitor #2 (as it is at the picture bellow) till I decide to close it (clicking the Desktop app or any other).

[image]

After clicking somewhere in Monitor #1, desktop is shown (picture bellow):

[image]

I'm using "Extend these displays" option for Multiple displays.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Task bar belongs to Monitor #1.

Comment: I think, this guy wants to run 2 Modern/Metro UI apps, one on each monitor. Basically he needs the same thing - not closing the Modern/Metro UI when interacting with the other screen...And the question responds to the RTM (from August).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure you can't. Metro seems to be only allowed on one monitor and other monitors will default to desktop.